# How to find f'(0) when a certain limit and condition are given.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I have this Calculus 1 question as a homework and I was wondering how it is possible to prove that f'(0)=0 as the solution says. [image]

I just can't seem to understand how to deal with this problem.
Thank you everyone!

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous and differentiable then the limit is just equal to the value at that point.  So $f(f(0))=\pi * f(0^2)$.  I think this makes it easier to solve.

Comment: @lordoftheshadows: How can you use that to help solve the problem? Since $f(0) = 0$, the equation you have is vacuously true.

Comment: @copper.hat You make a good point.  I missed that.  I think you can make an argument with analysis that this is true but I don't think that's what OP wants.

Comment: Its funny how often people forget to add the requirement that f be continuously differentiable or two times continuously differentiable in this sort of lhopital's rule problems.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo: I believe you do not need continuity of $f'$ here.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need continuity of $f'$.

Suppose $d = f'(0) \neq 0$.

Then ${f(f(x)) \over f(x^2)} = { f(f(x)) - f(f(0)) \over f(x) - f(0)} { f(x) -f(0) \over x-0} {x-0\over x^2 -0} {x^2 - 0 \over f(x^2) -f(0)} = {1 \over x} { f(f(x)) - f(f(0)) \over f(x) - f(0)} { f(x) -f(0) \over x-0} {x^2 - 0 \over f(x^2) -f(0)}$.

Now note that $\lim_{x \to 0} { f(f(x)) - f(f(0)) \over f(x) - f(0)} { f(x) -f(0) \over x-0} {x^2 - 0 \over f(x^2) -f(0)} = d$.

Comment: why is the limit in the bottom equal to $d$?

Comment: The first term has limit $d$, the second, $d$, and the third ${1 \over d}$. (The fact that $d \neq 0$ means that $f(x) \neq 0$ for $x$ close to $0$.)

Comment: oh yeah,nice!${}{}$

Comment: How does proving that it equals d proves that f'(0) = 0?

Comment: @YouXiaoRuan: If the limit on the last line converges to $d \neq 0$, then the previous line's limit will diverge to $\pm \infty$, which contradicts the limit in the question.

Comment: +1 for the very nice approach via contradiction

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $f(f(x))$ and $f(x^2)$ approach $0$ when $x$ goes to $0$ (by continuity of $f$).

Hence we can use l'Hôpital  to obtain:

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{f'(f(x))f'(x)}{2xf'(x^2)}=\pi$.

Suppose that $f'(0)=d$ with $d\neq 0$, then we can use continuity of $f'$ to obtain:

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{f'(f(x))f'(x)}{f'(x^2)}=\frac{d^2}{d}=d$, and so $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{f'(f(x))f'(x)}{2xf'(x^2)}=\infty$.

We deduce $f'(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Taylor's theorem lets us write
$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)\,x+o(|x|)=f'(0)\,x+o(|x|),$$
from where
$$
\pi=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(f(x))}{f(x^2)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(0)^2x+o(|x|)}{f'(0)\,x^2+o(|x|^2)},
$$
which is absurd if $f'(0)\neq0$.

Answer (score 0):

f(x^2) is an even function. If f(x) was an odd function then f(f(+dx)) would have the opposite sign as f(f(-dx)). That would make it impossible for the limit as x -> 0+ and x ->0- of f(f(x))/f(x^2) to both be equal to pi. Thus f(x) must be locally even about x=0, and as an immediate consequence f'(x) must be zero at x=0.